# ¿Mathematical induction GRE math?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, gre-exam

Im studing for the GRE math subject test...i can´t get the followin problem:

Using Mathematical Induction, show that it is possible to color with only two colors the regions formed by n lines in the plane.

Any idea on how to aproach it?

Answer (score 8):

HINT: When you add an $(n+1)$-st line to a plane that already has $n$ lines and has been suitably colored, you can invert the colors on one side of the new line. (By *invert the colors* I mean change blue regions to red and red to blue, if blue and red are the two colors.)